# Is there a danger to creating a js file that simply uses document.write() to bundle js and css files?

Tags: javascript, bundling-and-minification

I am building a front-end UI framework for developers in my firm to use to build internal web apps. It consists of customized Bootstrap, jQuery, other open-source libraries, internal modules and stylesheets. The user environment is entirely IE9 and my server is .NET 3.5. I am hosting the shared files. Dev teams in the firm will place the links in their project pages and apply the framework to their pages.

I want to offer them the simplest method of implementing this which would be one line of code to paste that builds the library for them. Cutting and pasting 30 lines of code is stale the moment <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> is pressed, it leaves me no control and is simply inelegant.

**Failed Experiments**

I tried using [Head.js](https://github.com/headjs)  and [LazyLoad](https://github.com/rgrove/lazyload)  both of which use best practices for inserting scripts. But each of them has caused either content to display before styled or conditions where methods are called before scripts load. I am giving up on this approach.
It's too volatile.

**A simple document.write() solution**

Over the weekend, I thought: Why don't I just make a js file named "framework,js", add the script and link files in order with a stack of document.write() lines. Tell developers to put it in the head and that's it. Heck I could add the necessary metatags for IE9 and mobile too for that matter. It's so nasty and simple... but it just might work!

The user base is on an internal network and of limited size. Bandwidth is not a problem. I'll test performance before I choose this. I can direct the developer teams on where to place the link.

**Knowing this and providing it actually works, is there any reason why I shouldn't do this?**

My only other option to explore is bundling on the server. I am hoping not to have to resort to this since I don't own the server myself and I am not a .NET developer.

Comment: Yes you are crazy... is this what you want?

Comment: Reworded to be more constructive. e-sushi, no one will be turning off javascript. These are internal web apps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your proposed approach is an excellent one for your situation. It has several advantages over the more sophisticated solutions, including utter simplicity, completely predictable order of execution, and full compatibility with scripts that may not lend themselves to asynchronous loading. I have used it many times in production applications, as have many other developers.

Of course the other solutions have their advantages too, but for what you're doing there is nothing wrong with good old `document.write()`.

It sounds like you have a number of scripts and stylesheets and are probably loading them from a common directory (or a common root directory). To reduce repetition in your `framework.js` file, you might want to define two functions, one to write a `<link>` tag for CSS and another to write a `<script>` tag for JavaScript. So a skeleton `framework.js` file might look something like this:

```
(function() {
    var scriptBase = 'js/';
    var styleBase = 'css/';

    function writeStyle( name ) {
        document.write(
            '<link rel="stylesheet" href="', styleBase, name, '">',
            '</link>'
        );
    }

    function writeScript( name ) {
        document.write(
            '<script src="', scriptBase, name, '">',
            '</script>'
        );
    }

    writeStyle( 'one.css' );
    writeStyle( 'two.css' );

    writeScript( 'one.js' );
    writeScript( 'two.js' );
})();
```

Note that you don't have to do any special escaping of the `</script>` text as you may see in code that uses `document.write()`. That's only necessary when you're putting this code directly inside a `<script>` tag within the HTML file. The purpose of that escaping is to prevent the enclosing `<script>` tag from being closed by the `</script>` text inside the `document.write()` call. Since your code is in an external `.js` file this is not an issue: the presence of the `</script>` text inside this file won't terminate the `.js` file.

Another point to keep in mind is that all of the `document.write()` calls you make inside a `.js` file are inserted into the document *after* the `.js` file that writes them. So don't expect to be able to do a `document.write()` inside `framework.js` and then have other code *inside* `framework.js` that depends on the `.js` file you just wrote. All of those `.js` files (and `.css`) are loaded after `framework.js`, not interleaved with it.

One more consideration, of course, is load time. Your page could load faster if you combine and minify your CSS and JS files. But if these are internal web apps, page load time may be the least of your worries: reliability and maintainability may be more important. And in any case you can always use the `document.write()` solution to get up and running right now, and later optimize this only in the unlikely event that you need to.

Comment: It is working like a charm. Page loads on my test  ~200ms on initial load and ~100 on subsequent ones. The files are loaded in exact order. I tried docw.riting the IE meta tag as well but IE complains the page is already finalized. Thanks for the encouragement. I'll leave the answer open for a while so others might chime in but we're looking good.

Comment: It works. Pageloads average 100ms. Different development platforms. Thanks for the encouragement to go this route.